# Blank screen on PHP5 and Apache 2.4

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Good Evening,
I installed Apache2, MySQL and PHP5 on Debian 8 using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql
```

Apache2 works fine (default index.html), but when I create a webpage (info.php) with the following code in it:

```
<? php phpinfo(); ?>
```

it displays a blank page. When I looked into the logs, there was not any errors there

Comment: Error logs. What's in them? Did you look? This is the first thing you need to do because otherwise that could be just about anything. Does view source show your PHP code being run or do you see literally that in there?

Comment: make sure you have `short_open_tag=On` and no other `short_open_tag=` in `php.ini`. Oh, looks like your tag is just wrong, but looked like a short tag at first. However, that would have thrown an undefined constant error, if short tags were enabled, so fix that anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should not be:

```
<? php phpinfo(); ?>
```

should be:

```
<?=phpinfo(); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about the space. When I changed to <? php, it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this on your php code

```
<?php 

ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');


?>
```

and change your page to

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

you had a blank space in the `< ?php` tag

Answer (score 0):

Should be `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.